# How can I unit test a controller using altered default date binding?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, controller, spock

How can I simulate the behavior of **grails.databinding.dateFormats** in a controller spock test?

In my Config.groovy, I added these settings:

```
grails.databinding.dateFormats = [
    'yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSSX',
    'yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ssX',
]
```

What do I have to do to get the unit test framework to bind date properties using one of the specified formats?

My controller looks like:

```
class MyController {
    static responseFormats = ['json']

    def get() {
        MyCommand command = bindData(new MyCommand(), params)

        command.validate()
        if (command.hasErrors()) {
            ...
        }
        else {
            //...do stuff with command object
        }
    }

    @Validateable
    class MyCommand {
        Long resourceId
        Date startDate
        Date endDate
        static constraints = {
            resourceId nullable: false
            startDate nullable: false
            endDate nullable: false
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the application, this code works normally; however, when bindData() is called in the unit test, the 'resourceId' property on the command object is populated, while the date properties are not.

Comment: Add the unit spec to the question as well.

Comment: Those are ISO 8601 formats. You don't need any configuration. In any case, databinding.dateFormats configuration works just fine in tests.